# IC and BC curve with anchor at specific points

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm trying to make the following figure:

[image].

How could I find the specific point where the anchor of Δ(c2) ends and Δ(c1) starts? Is there a way to name it or I should try it by trial-and-error numbering?

My code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick, ->] (0,0)--(0,4) node[left]{$c_2$};
\draw[very thick, ->](0,0)--(4,0) node[below]{$c_1$};
\draw[thick, -](3.5,0) node[above right]{BC}--(0,3.5);
\draw[thick, color=blue, domain=0.8:4] plot (\x,{(3.1)/(\x)}) node[right]{IC};
\fill (1.7,1.8) circle (2pt);
\fill (1.25,2.5) circle (2pt);
\draw[dashed] (0,1.8) node[left]{$c_2^1$}--(1.7,1.8) node[above right](b){B};
\draw[dashed] (1.7,0) node[below]{$c_1^1$}--(1.7,1.8);
\draw[dashed] (0,2.5) node[left]{$c_2^2$}--(1.25,2.5) node[above right](a){A};
\draw[dashed] (1.25,0) node[below]{$c_1^2$}--(1.25,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: (1) Much smarter to define A and B to be coordinates on the blue line, then say `c_1^1` is at `(B |- 0,0)`, `c_2^1` is at `(B -| 0,0)`. The crossing can be done via `\path let \p1=(A),\p2=(B) in (\x1,\y2) coordinate (C);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what `daleif` proposed but similar.

Once `nodes` A and B are defined, the wanted intersection is at `(A|-B)` coordinate. Then it's easy to draw desired braces.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[axis/.style={very thick, ->},
    dot/.style={circle, minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, fill=black, label={45:#1}},
    mybrace/.style={decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, raise=3pt}}]

\draw[axis] (0,0) coordinate (origin) --(0,4) node[left]{$c_2$};
\draw[axis](0,0)--(4,0) node[below]{$c_1$};
\draw[thick, -](3.5,0) node[above right]{BC}--(0,3.5);
\draw[thick, color=blue, domain=0.8:4] plot (\x,{(3.1)/(\x)})  node[right]{IC};
\node[dot=B] at (1.7,1.8) (B) {};
\node[dot=A] at (1.25,2.5) (A) {};
\draw[dashed] (origin|-A) node[left]{$c_2^2$} -| (origin-|A)  node[below] {$c_1^2$};
\draw[dashed] (origin|-B) node[left]{$c_2^1$} -| (origin-|B)  node[below] {$c_1^1$};
\draw[mybrace, red] (A.center) -- node[red, left=1mm, font=\tiny] {$\Delta(c2)$} (A|-B);
\draw[mybrace, red] (A|-B) -- node[red, below=1mm, font=\tiny] {$\Delta(c1)$} (B.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, of course, that is easier than using let, +1